# AWS Powershell 6 bug in Get-IAMCredentialReport

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

The AWS powershell version 4.0.2.0 seems to have a bug.  When I execute 
`Get-IAMCredentialReport -AsTextArray` on a computer running the new version (4.0.2.0) I get output like this

```
Content                  Generated Time     ReportFormat

System.IO.MemoryStream    1/18/2020         text/csv
```

But the same command on a computer running AWS Powershell 3.3 give me the output of the file.

Anybody else seeing this?  Any advise?

Comment: Did you used `Request-IAMCredentialReport` before it?

Comment: Yes I did. Both commands had the file available